# C++ placing dll in relative path to exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I built a small .exe application. Currently I take the compiled .exe file and all necessary .dll's and put them in one folder. So it looks like this: (**working**)

```
appfolder/
    lib1.dll
    lib2.dll
    ...
    app.exe
```

I'd like to organize it and bring it in following form: (**not working**)

```
appfolder/
    libs/
        lib1.dll
        lib2.dll
        ...
    app.exe
```

However, I do not find a way to make this work. I'm using VS2010 where I tried to add ".\libs" to the Additional Include Directories (Project Properties > Configuration > C/C++).

I also read about LoadLibrary which seems to be not a solution to this problem...

Is that possible at all?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Compilation, linking, runtime failure?

Comment: If libraries cannot be loaded at runtime, you need to change Executable directories, and not Include directories. However, it is better to keep all executables in the same directory. In multiproject workspace all executables are placed in Solution directory/Debug(Release), it must work by default.

Comment: The first form is working. When I try to run the exe in the second form I get an error that an dll could not be found.

Comment: If I change the Executable directories for the second form, it's giving me the same error.

Comment: It is always better to keep all solution executables in the same directory. By this way you can, for example, run .exe from Windows Explorer. Just use default VS multi-project solution (all executables in solution Debug/Release dir). You can also copy all executables to output directory in post-build step.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `SetDllDirectory` function will work for you see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203(v=vs.85).aspx).

Besides this you can use `LoadLibraryEx` and `GetProcAddress` to do "lazy" loading.

Similar function also exist for Linux.